# Only replace numbers that have a 1 as first character?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a string `1020 1050 9784 1560 0231 1546 8745`.

How would I remove (using regular expressions) only the number groups that have a 1 as the first number?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Also, why do you think it needs to use regular expressions?

Comment: Regular expressions are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using word boundary (`\b`):

```
\b1\d*\b
```

`\b` matches between word character (`\w`) and non-word character(`\W`), or match between word character and begin/end of the string.

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven, I added an explanation. I hope that will help you understand the pattern.

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven, You can specify the empty string as a replacement string; which result the matched part removed.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to only let it work for numbers that are 4 digits long? Sorry for asking another question.

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven, No problem. Use `\b1\d{3}\b` as a pattern.

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven, `{n}` means that it should match preceding pattern *n* times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you would find all words that start with 1

```
$s="1020 1050 9784 1560 0231 1546 8745";
preg_match_all("#\b1.*?\b#",$s,$res);
var_dump($res);
```

And the result is:

```
array(1) {
   [0]=>
    array(4) {
        [0]=>
         string(4) "1020"
        [1]=>
         string(4) "1050"
        [2]=>
         string(4) "1560"
        [3]=>
         string(4) "1546"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = "1020 1050 9784 1560 0231 1546 8745";

echo $str."<br/>";

$str = preg_replace("^(\b0[0-9]{3}|[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\b)^","",$str);

echo $str;
```

This will remove any 4 digit numbers that do not begin with a 1.

Comment: I would avoid using  "^" as delimiters